# Why does the gsub function in R doesn't work on '.' operator?

Tags: r, gsub

I have an array named myfile which has all the dates in character format. 
For eg - "2014.01.29" "2014.02.02" "2014.01.09" "2014.01.23" "2014.01.09" "2014.01.29"

Now, I want to replace this '.' operator to '-'. So I want "2014.01.29" to be like "2014-01-29". 
When I use the code

```
 gsub('.' ,  '-' ,  myfile[1])
```

I get the output as   '----------'. The command works absolutely normal when I replace '.' in gsub with anything else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its an array. Doesn't work myfile [,1]. Gives an error "Error in myfile[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: Is it a 3D array or a matrix

Comment: . is the wildcard character, it matches everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`  which can be done either putting it in a `[.]` or `\\.`.

```
  gsub('[.]', '-', myfile[1])
```

or

```
 gsub('\\.', '-', myfile[1])
```

Comment: As it is an array myfile [,1] doesn't work. myfile [1] works perfect. Thank You.